# Hemoglobin subunits genes in scRNA-seq

Tags: gene, scrnaseq

In one scRNA-seq sample I encountered the genes: Hbb-bs, Hba-a1 and Hba-a2. These genes appear on top of the list of the highest expressed genes but the 75% percentile of cells have very low counts. Therefore the expression is highly skewed.

[image]

Reading from [gene cards](https://www.genecards.org/cgi-bin/carddisp.pl?gene=HBB&keywords=hbb-bs), they appear to be coding hemoglobin subunits and involved in oxygen transport. I think they may need to be removed before normalization, also because the analysis I'm running does not consider oxygen transport.

Has anyone encountered this situation and what do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have red blood cell contamination.  It's probably better to identify which cells they are.  They'll probably cluster away from the cells you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

They may be B cells, did you analysis if they have b cell marker?